# Migrating existing users to Thinktecture IdentityServer

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3, thinktecture

I have an ASP.NET application with Forms Authentication. There is a `users` table in the DB with `Id`, `UserName`, `PasswordHash` and `PasswordSalt`.

Is it possible to migrate these users over to a fresh Thinktecture IdentityServer installation while keeping their existing credentials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't migrate users TO identity server. You would rather implement a user service to connect identity server to your existing user store.

see here:
https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/userService.html

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.